# Position of "iconfont" element in IE (all version) is wrong

Tags: internet-explorer, meteor, position, icon-fonts

I used this [package](https://atmospherejs.com/andrefgneves/iconfont) on Meteor project for my custom icons font. And I have a problem with position of icons elements in IE browsers (all versions). It just goes up - like this

[image]

There is an element *:before* and *:before* just go to UP. Any ideas?